# Freemarker print list map

Tags: java, list, dictionary, freemarker

```
List<Atribute> atributes= new ArrayList<>();
atributes.add(new Atribute("aa","1"));
atributes.add(new Atribute("aa","2"));
atributes.add(new Atribute("aa","3"));

Map<String, Object> mapOne = new HashMap();
mapOne.put("ClasseName", atributes);

Map mapFreemarker = new HashMap();
mapFreemarker.put("mapFull", mapOne);
```

How can I print mapOne and atributes list in freemarker?

Print map in freemarker??????????

```
<#list mapFull as obj>  

     ClasseName
         aa -- 1
         aa -- 2
         aa -- 3

</#list>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't described the `Attribute` class, let's assume it has (at least) two fields named `name` and `count` and initialized with the constructor, and the appropriate getters. Then:

```
<ul>
[#list mapFull?keys as key]
    <li>
        ${key}
        <ul>
        [#list mapFull[key] as val]
            <li>${val.name} -- ${val.count}</li>
        [/#list]
        </ul>
    </li>
[/#list]
</ul>
```